# getting MismatchSenderId with firebase serverside

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, phonegap

I am trying to send the notification using a php script that is stored in my server and I am getting the MismatchSenderId.

```
$to="device_id";
$title="MYAPP Push";
$message=" MYAPP Push Notification Message";

sendPush($to,$title,$message);

function sendPush($to,$title,$message){
  // API access key from Google API's Console
  // replace API
  define( "API_ACCESS_KEY", "server_key_provided_by_firebase");

  $registrationIds = array($to);

  $msg = array(
    'message' => $message,
    'title' => $title,
    'vibrate' => 1,
    'sound' => 1
    // you can also add images, additionalData
  );

  $fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
    'data' => $msg
  );

  $headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  );

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
  curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
  curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
  curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
  $result = curl_exec($ch );

  curl_close( $ch );
  echo $result;
}
```

Here the error I get when I run the php script:
`{"multicast_id":7804476702639319453,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}`

I've checked every single question here in stackoverflow and could not solve it.

I am using firebase (spark plan) and developing the app with Phonegap. I believe that has nothing to do with the app

Any Ideas???

Answer (score 1):

Copy your google-service.json file to root folder (that contains www, config.xml etc).

Step 1:
Login to your firebase console.

[image]

Step 2:
On Project Overview Settings, Copy the **Cloud Messaging ServerKey**

My key ex:

```
`AAAAjXzVMKY:APA91bED4d53RX.....bla bla
```

Step 3:
Replace the key

```
define( "API_ACCESS_KEY", "My key");
```

Finally Test the app :D

I sent push notification using node succesfully.

```js
var gcm = require('node-gcm');

// Replace these with your own values.
var apiKey = "MY_SERVER_KEY";
var deviceID = "MY_DEVICE_ID";

var service = new gcm.Sender(apiKey);
var message = new gcm.Message();
message.addData('title', 'Hi');
message.addData('body', 'BLA BLA BLA BLA');
message.addData('actions', [
  { "icon": "accept", "title": "Accept", "callback": "app.accept"},
  { "icon": "reject", "title": "Reject", "callback": "app.reject"},
]);

service.send(message, { registrationTokens: [ deviceID ] }, function (err, response) {
 if(err) console.error(err);
 else  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: I did that but still getting the MismatchSenderId. Do I have to do this from a specific domain or not?

Comment: @RaffaeleColleo Please refer this Phonegap Push notification workshop [Here](http://macdonst.github.io/push-workshop/)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for this error](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) states:

> A registration token is tied to a certain group of senders. When a
>   client app registers for FCM, it must specify which senders are
>   allowed to send messages. You should use one of those sender IDs when
>   sending messages to the client app. If you switch to a different
>   sender, the existing registration tokens won't work.

You should double check that you are using the Server Key from the same project used to generate the `google-services.json` file the app was built with.  The `project_number` at the top of the `google-services.json` file must be the same as the Sender ID shown in the project settings Cloud Messaging tab of the Firebase Console.

Comment: Hi @Bob. It is. The file google-services is on the folder root of the project (same place as config.xml). Should it be placed on the www folder?

Thanks

Comment: @RaffaeleColleo:  Sorry--don't know.  I'm not familiar with Cordova builds.

Comment: Can Anyone help me on this matter?